# How to extract a specific file version from a ZPAQ archive

Tags: backup, archive

Recently, I've been looking into ZPAQ, which can do versioned backups of files and directories. A big plus of [ZPAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZPAQ) is that it not only compresses data, but also deduplicates redundant blocks of data.

The manual is not clear on how to retrieve a specific version of a file (or a directory). Apparently, the archive needs to be rolled back to a previous state, and then I can extract the file/directory - but the manual is not clear on how to do that.

With `zpaq l myarchive.zpaq -all` I can inspect the file versions, with their file sizes and dates. The file version is the four-digit number in front of `/mytext.txt`.

```
zpaq v7.15 journaling archiver, compiled Mar 22 2020
mytext.zpaq: 4 versions, 4 files, 4 fragments, 0.004125 MB

- 2022-04-06 10:39:33            7       0001/ +1 -0 -> 796
- 2022-04-06 10:39:23            7  0664 0001/mytext.txt
- 2022-04-06 10:40:02           16       0002/ +1 -0 -> 1107
- 2022-04-06 10:39:59           16  0664 0002/mytext.txt
- 2022-04-06 10:43:29          112       0003/ +1 -0 -> 1115
- 2022-04-06 10:43:18          112  0664 0003/mytext.txt
- 2022-04-06 10:44:10           18       0004/ +1 -0 -> 1107
- 2022-04-06 10:44:07           18  0664 0004/mytext.txt

0.000153 MB of 0.000153 MB (8 files) shown
  -> 0.000153 MB (4 refs to 4 of 4 frags) after dedupe
  -> 0.004125 MB compressed.
0.019 seconds (all OK)
```

But how to extract a specific version of a specific file?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I found it was

```
zpaq x myarchive.zpaq -until 2
```

which extracts the entire archive, version number 2. (Version 1 would be the oldest stored version.)

On the other hand,

```
zpaq x myarchive.zpaq myfile.txt -until -1
```

extracts the second most recent version of `myfile.txt`.